# html bootstrap dropdown get index of selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

There are many answers in stackoverflow about how to get the selected value of a bootstrap dropdown

```
<div class="input-group">                                            
    <input type="TextBox" ID="datebox" Class="form-control"></input>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="demolist" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no problem with that using

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){    
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().html($(this).html() + '<span class="caret"></span>');    
    })
```

but after that I need to make a HTTP request with several values, and one of this is the index of the selected item of the dropdown '0' for 'A', '1' for 'B' and '2' for 'C'

How can I get the index of the selected item?

Comment: $('#ldemolist li').index() try this to get the index of li ref :https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: `$(this).closest('li').index()` or `$(this).parent().index()`  should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sending the request outside of `click` handler scope, you can set a variable with a *null* value and update it on `.click()`

```
var selected_index = null;
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){    
  $(this).parent().parent().prev().html($(this).html() + '<span class="caret"></span>');
  selected_index = $(this).closest('li').index();
});

// ... HTTP request code with selected_index
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){    
        $(this).parent().parent().prev().html($(this).html() + '<span class="caret"></span>');    
        var clicked_li_index = $("#demolist li").index( $(this).parent()) );
        alert(clicked_li_index);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `.index()` , also you can remove the additional `</input>` in ur code

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `index()` method to do that.

> **[.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)**
>
> *Search for a given element from among the matched elements.*

Here is an example

```js
var $dropDownItems = $('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-menu').children();

$dropDownItems.on('click', function() {
  console.log('index: ', $dropDownItems.index(this), 'text: ', this.textContent)
})
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```